# Laravel Passport CreateFreshApiToken middleware vs web middleware

Tags: laravel, rest, authentication, laravel-passport, laravel-middleware

If i understand right, the `CreateFreshApiToken`-middleware uses a cookie-based authentication mechanism (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript). Accordingly the use of csrf-protection makes sense.

What exactly is the difference between using the `CreateFreshApiToken`-middleware or simply accessing my API through the `web`-middleware, since both seem to be stateful.

In my scenario im working on a `laravel-module` (https://nwidart.com/laravel-modules/v6/introduction) which is supposed to be a REST-API. This API can only be accessed by authenticated user and also consumes user informations. The main module/platform uses a normal web authentication through a login form. The user informations are stored in the main module/platform.

What would be the best way to implement the REST-API module stateless (based on the authentication) and without interfering with the web-authentication which is used by the main module.

Should i considere making the API not restful?